# Вывод из txt файла

Tags: php

Есть текстовый файл с ip-адресами:

```
192.168.4.1:20
192.168.4.1:2065
192.168.4.1:203
192.168.4.1:20234
192.168.4.1:2068
```

Нужно с помощью PHP вывести на страницу эти ip в формате:

```
"какой-то текст" ip "бла бла бла" порт
```

Comment: С PHP не знаком, но уверен, что нужная вам функция называется split.

Comment: @VladD вы зря недооцениваете PHP! Ибо это [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). Там, кстати, и `join()` только в виде алиаса существует.

Comment: @Etki: Виноват, погорячился, был неправ.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о работе непосредственно с файлом, то необходимо сначала считать его. [Есть множество вариантов для работы с файлами в php.](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=fs&page=005)
Лично моё решение выглядит так: взять содержимое файла в массив через функцию `file();` и потом уже делать с этим массивом всё, что вздумается.
PHP-код готового решения:

```
$input_txt = file("ip.txt");
foreach( $input_txt as $value )
{
    $ip_port=explode(":",$value);
    echo "какой-то текст ".$ip_port[0]." бла бла бла ".$ip_port[1]."\n";
}
```

содержание ip.txt:

```
192.168.4.1:20
192.168.4.1:2065
192.168.4.1:203
192.168.4.1:20234
192.168.4.1:2068
```

Текстовый файл должен лежать в одном каталоге с php-файлом, иначе - поменяйте путь к нему в параметре функции `file();`.

Решение не претендует на идеальное, но оно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужная функция называется `str_replace()`.
Поскольку именно она используется, когда мы хотим заменить один текст на другой - как это следует из задачи. 
Напомню также, что символ перевода строки в РНР можно записать как `"\n"`.

Этот способ куда проще, чем теребенькаться с массивами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$in = "
127.34.56.2:87
84.67.54.68:8888
87.65.43.21:80
";

$out = implode("\n", preg_replace('/(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?):(\d+)/', 'IP: $0, Port: $1', explode("\n", $in))); // explode разделяет по \n, каждая строка проверяется регуляркой, совпадения заменяются и implode опять собирает в строку по переносу - \n

var_dump($out);
/*
string(96) "
IP: 127.34.56.2:87, Port: 87
IP: 84.67.54.68:8888, Port: 8888
IP: 87.65.43.21:80, Port: 80
"
*/
```