# Вывод определенной строки из txt на страницу HTML

Tags: php, вывод

За год наплодилось море лендингов с одними и теме же товарами и их вариациями, где очень трудоемко стало обновлять цены. Ищу решение чтобы держать цены в одном файле, а на лендинги их как-то выводить. Но не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста какое-нибудь решение.

например: в файле хранить цены на 15 моделей телефонов (с какими-то тегами или метками, а не просто номер), и есть 4-5 лендинга на каждом по 3-5 телефона, иногда повторяются.

[Вывод из txt файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424352/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-txt-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)
вот это было близко, но тут выводится всё содержимое, а мне бы как-то конкретную строчку выбирать бы.

Comment: а просто в js внести кучу всяких `var` и выводиться их куда надо , вариант ?

Comment: а в переменную `var` вносить из php

Comment: @МаксимЛенский создать в `js` кучу всяких переменных - гениальнее ответа не видал...

Comment: @Appler в чем проблема хранить в БД? индексированный поиск куда приятнее работы с файлами (хотя и медленнее, но разницы вы не почувствуете).

Comment: @Manitikyl а в чём проблема то ? так нельзя делать ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну не желательно, уровень костыльности в вашем совете - зашкаливает.

Comment: @Manitikyl кастыль не кастыль а работать будет с большевистким энтузиазмом

Comment: толку минусовать если у него 1 бал всего ... только себе минусы ставите

Comment: Может лучше не переменные в JS, а хранить на сервере JSON, и из него выбирать нужные данные.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский за вопрос - себе минус не ставится, а вот за ответ - да. У меня минус 2 за 2 ответа, но я готов пожертвовать 2 баллами за такие ответы...

Comment: @misdeed  вы минус ставите кому то и у вас же тоже высчитывают ...1 отнимают

Answer (score 1):

> ...Вывод из txt файла вот это было близко, но тут выводится всё
>   содержимое, а мне бы как-то конкретную строчку выбирать бы...

Достаточно зайти сюда: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php

Видим:

> file — Читает содержимое файла и помещает его в массив

Т.е. есть у нас файл `FILE.TXT` с содержимым:

```
Строка 0
Строка 1
Строка 2
Строка 3
```

Чтобы вывести `Строка 2`, нужно всего-лишь:

```
$INPUT_FILE = file("FILE.TXT");
echo $INPUT_FILE[2];
```

Comment: Только вторая строка - это `$INPUT_FILE[1];`

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko имелось в виду `Строка 2`, подправил

Answer (score -1):

Где хранить - в базе данных. Как выбирать конкретную строчку - через `where` в SQL-запросе.

Если хотите более конкретный ответ, задавайте более конкретный вопрос.